# This Java code is running perfectly in IDE but not on codechef. Can anyone tell me why this exception is coming?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader, parsefloat

It's working fine in IDE but got null pointer exception on Codechef.

on the second line "parseFloat" it's getting null pointer exception

can anyone solve this issue?

```
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            float am = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
            float bal = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
            BufferedWriter ot = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
            if((am <= bal) && am%5 == 0) {
                float ball = bal - am;
                ball -= 0.50;
                String.format("%.5f", ball);
                ot.write(String.valueOf(bal));
            }
```

Comment: [dovumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) of `readLine()`: "**Returns:** ... null if the end of the stream has been reached" (usually input from IDE is not closed automatically, while probably that site is closing it)

Comment: Because there is no line to read => it returns null

Comment: But why? It's taking input on IDE but not on Codechef. Can you tell me where I can make some changes?

Comment: @user16320675 can you tell me what I can do to make it work on Codechef?

Comment: @user16320675 ok I'm checking on what you said

Comment: Why would anyone want to wrap `System.out` in a `BufferedWriter` and then later write `ot.write(String.valueOf(bal));` instead of directly using `System.out.print(bal);`?

Comment: My guess is that you have not implemented the requirements correctly.  But since you haven't told us what the (complete) requirements are, this is only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should give two lines via the site.
@user16320675 mentioned that you probably didn't give them.